# What is the meaning of eigenvalue here

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

How can I find the eigenvalue that is smallest  .?

Apply the inverse power method to approximate, for the matrix $A$, the eigenvalue that is smallest in magnitude. Use the given initial vector 
$x_0$, $k$
 iterations, and three-decimal-place accuracy.
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
4 &1 &0\\ 
0 &6 &5\\
0 &1 &3\end{bmatrix},$$

$$x_0 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\  1\\  1\end{bmatrix},$$ $3$ iterations

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format. We prefer if you type everything, rather than use images.

Comment: "Eigenvalue that is smallest in magnitude" means "eigenvalue closest to zero" or "eigenvalue whose absolute value is the smallest."

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalue smallest in magnitude means the eigenvalue with the smallest absolute value.